JNA getting com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: Class not registered
I'm trying to test the ability of calling a COM compiled from C# in a Java application using JNA.
C# code:
namespace MyComLibrary { 

  [Guid("SOME_GUID")]
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
  public partial interface TestTLBInf
  {
      [DispId(1)]
      String getData();
  }

  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("OTHER_GUID")]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  [ProgId("AppInterface.Test")]
  public partial class Test : TestTLBInf
  {

    public String getData()
    {
        return "test";
    }
  }
}

And the Java code:
public class JNATest {
    private static final String CLSID = "OTHER_GUID";
    private static final String IID = "SOME_GUID";
    private static final String LIB_NAME = "LIB_NAME";
    private static final String LIB_PATH = "LIB_PATH";
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", LIB_PATH);
        Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
        try {
            NativeMethodsCls cls = NativeMethodsCls.create();
            cls.test();
        } finally {
            Ole32.INSTANCE.CoUninitialize();
        }
    }
        
    public static class NativeMethodsCls extends Unknown {
        
        private NativeMethodsCls(Pointer pvInstance) {
            super(pvInstance);
        }
    
        public static NativeMethodsCls create(){
            PointerByReference p = new PointerByReference();
            GUID classId = Ole32Util.getGUIDFromString(CLSID);
            GUID interfaceId = Ole32Util.getGUIDFromString(IID);
            WinNT.HRESULT hr = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoCreateInstance(classId, null, WTypes.CLSCTX_SERVER, interfaceId, p);
            COMUtils.checkRC(hr);
            NativeMethodsCls handler = new NativeMethodsCls(p.getValue());
            return handler;
        }
    
        public void test(){
            Object result = this._invokeNativeObject(1, null, String.class);
            System.out.println(result);
            COMUtils.checkRC(new HRESULT(result));
        }
    }
}

This test yields

com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: Class not registered(HRESULT: 80040154)

After the compilation and registration of the DLL, I verified that the GUID exists in the registry editor. The DLL was compiled with x86 and any CPU, neither worked.
I had a different solution that failed where I tried to load the library first, declare an interface with method with the same name as in the C# but got no such method exception.
How can I solve this exception?

If DLL is compiled with x86, i.e. 32-bit, is 32-bit Java being used? Probably COM component and Java process should have the same bitness.
